# Рекурсивное удаление файлов и директорий

Tags: python, python-3.x, файловая-система

Есть скрипт, который по временному штампу удаляет файлы. Удаление с рекурсией, отчищаются и вложенные директории. После работы скрипта, остаются пустые директории. Подскажите, как еще удалить и отчищенные директории.

```
import os
import datetime

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(r'C:\py\dir_for_remove'):
   for file in filenames:
      curpath = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
      file_modified = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(curpath))
      if datetime.datetime.now() - file_modified > datetime.timedelta(minutes=5):
          os.remove(curpath)
```

Comment: если Вас устроил ответ нажмите на галочку, которая слева от ответа и человеку написавшему его будет приятно.

Answer (score 6):

Попробуйте этот вариант:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\py\dir_for_remove', topdown=False):
    for file in files:
        curpath = os.path.join(root, file)
        file_modified = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(curpath))
        if datetime.now() - file_modified > timedelta(minutes=5):
            os.remove(curpath)

    # Проходим по директориями и удаляем пустые
    for d in dirs:
        curpath = os.path.join(root, d)
        if not os.listdir(curpath):
            os.rmdir(curpath)
```

---

`topdown=False` - меняет порядок обхода с конца в начало, что поможет при удалении папок

Comment: может быть завернуть в рекурсивную функцию? чтобы неограниченную вложенность также чистило?

Comment: Спасибо, вариант gil9red помог.

Comment: @EugeneDennis, `os.walk` сама по себе работает "рекурсивно" -- пройдет через все вложенные папки и файлы. На каждой итерации root -- текущая папка, а dirs и files -- вложенные папки и файлы

Comment: @Vadin, это хорошо, а то я не имел возможность протестировать :) Если вам помогло, оцените и примите ответ :)

Comment: @gil9red а папка внутри с пустыми папками не удалится походу по такому сценарию

Comment: @EugeneDennis, из-за обратного порядка прохода папок удалится

Comment: @Vadim, примите мой ответ, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 0):

А не проще ли удалить все рекурсивно?

Можно попробовать так:

```
import shutil

def recurcive_deletion(folder_name):
   shutil.rmtree(folder_name)
```

Comment: `shutil.rmtree` такое всё удалит, а нужны только пустые